# Split the given column in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to split the following table

| column |
| --- |
| {"senderName":"John David", "senderCountry":"LKA", "senderAddress":"No 230,ABS,11200} |

I want to get following table using oracle sql

| senderName | senderCountry | senderAddress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John David | LKA | No 230,ABS,11200 |

I tried the following code

```
SELECT
regexp_substr(column,'[^:]+', 1, 1) As senderName,
regexp_substr(column,'[^:]+', 1, 2) As senderCountry,
regexp_substr(column,'[^:]+', 1, 3) As senderAddress  
From table
```

But I got the following table

| senderName | senderCountry | senderAddress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "senderName" | "John David", "senderCountry" | "LKA", "senderAddress" |

Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Is it always JSON formatted?  Are you using Version 18c or greater?

Comment: My is version 12C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `JSON_TABLE` for this.

If you cannot and your JSON is very simple (i.e. the keys are only going to appear once and you do not have a complicated path to parse) then you can use regular expressions (but don't if you can use a proper JSON parser like `JSON_TABLE`):

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           column_name,
           '"senderName":\s*"((\\"|[^"])*)"',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           1
         ),
         '\"',
         '"'
       ) AS senderName,
       REPLACE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           column_name,
           '"senderCountry":\s*"((\\"|[^"])*)"',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           1
         ),
         '\"',
         '"'
       ) AS senderCountry,
       REPLACE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           column_name,
           '"senderAddress":\s*"((\\"|[^"])*)"',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           1
         ),
         '\"',
         '"'
       ) AS senderAddress  
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name CHECK (column_name iS JSON)) AS
SELECT '{"senderName":"John David", "senderCountry":"LKA", "senderAddress":"No 230,ABS,11200"}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{"senderName":"Jane Smith", "senderAddress":"No 42,\"Home\", XYZ, 98765", "senderCountry":"ABC"}' FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: Your JSON was invalid as it is missing a closing `"`.*

Outputs:

> | SENDERNAME | SENDERCOUNTRY | SENDERADDRESS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | John David | LKA | No 230,ABS,11200 |
> | Jane Smith | ABC | No 42,"Home", XYZ, 98765 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=729b177e4c408c7385548a3ef82e9efa)*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 18c or greater, you can just use `JSON_TABLE`:

```sql
WITH test_data (json) AS
(
  SELECT '{"senderName":"John David", "senderCountry":"LKA", "senderAddress":"No 230,ABS,11200"}' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT jt.*
FROM test_data td,
JSON_TABLE(td.json,
           '$'
           COLUMNS (senderName VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.senderName',
                    senderCountry VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.senderCountry',
                    senderAddress VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.senderAddress')) jt
```

This produces the following results:

| SENDERNAME | SENDERCOUNTRY | SENDERADDRESS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John David | LKA | No 230,ABS,11200 |

Here is a DBFiddle showing this working ([Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=260f626bd0a0a02d109bf229c636aede))

Comment: ORA-00406: COMPATIBLE parameter needs to be 12.0.0.0.0 or greater
00406. 00000 -  "COMPATIBLE parameter needs to be %s or greater"
*Cause:    The COMPATIBLE initialization parameter is not high
           enough to allow the operation. Allowing the command would make
           the database incompatible with the release specified by the
           current COMPATIBLE parameter.
*Action:   Shutdown and startup with a higher compatibility setting.
Error at Line: 24 Column: 1  @Del

Comment: It is no working for me.... Can we use regexp_substr()

Comment: For versions with `json_*` functions there's more readable and explicit `cross join lateral`. I may be very useful when the dataset need not be reduced when the correlated subquery is empty (by changing to `left join lateral`)

Comment: @LochanaT Even version 12.1 is coming to [End Of Life](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/742060_1.html) in a year, so `compatible` parameter should definitely be increased from ancient level value. JSON parsing with custom regex is painful an error prone

Answer (score 0):

It’s easier to split with `"`

```sql
with tab1 as (
select '{"senderName":"John David", "senderCountry":"LKA", "senderAddress":"No 230,ABS,11200"}' col from dual
)
select replace(regexp_substr(t1.col, '"[^"]+"',1, 2), '"', ''),
       replace(regexp_substr(t1.col, '"[^"]+"',1, 4), '"', ''),
       replace(regexp_substr(t1.col, '"[^"]+"',1, 6), '"', '')
  from tab1 t1
```

Comment: JSON data is not guaranteed to be in the same order. It can also contain escaped quotes in strings. This is going to have lots of potential to go wrong. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=942085ea07f121be6588b97afcd792c0)